# using concatMap to sequence multiple observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I'm trying to use RxJS concatMap to sequence my 2 observables so that it returns the employeeID before calling the service to return the object to bind to my Mat-Table in Angular 9. But I'm not sure how to write the syntax correctly. the first observable is actually a behavior subject that I created to let components subscribe to anywhere in the app. the second is an http response from a web api.

I've been looking at the example here and trying to figure it out but just been banging on the keyboard.
[RxJS concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap)

```
//first observable (actually a Behavior Subject)
this.userService.currentEmployeeId.subscribe(empId => this.employeeID = empId)

//second observable
this.service.getMissingContractsSummary(this.employeeID)
.subscribe(
  response => {        
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Contractsummary>(response);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it the following way:

```
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.userService.currentEmployeeId.pipe(
   concatMap(empId => this.service.getMissingContractsSummary(empId)),
).subscribe(response => {
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Contractsummary>(response);
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
});
```

There is a difference between `concatMap`, `switchMap`, `mergeMap`. In your example, I think I would switch `concatMap` for `switchMap` although most likely for your example using any of the 3 will do the trick.

https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/

Answer (score 4):

`concatMap` should work but depending on the behavior you want you may want to try `switchMap`. In either case, the syntax is similar. You will need to pipe that operation to the `currentEmployeeId` observable. When that emits a new value, the `switchMap` function can pass the value to your service's `get` function to return that observable. Then you can subscribe as you already have in your example code.

```js
this.userService.currentEmployeeId.pipe(
  switchMap(empId => this.service.getMissingContractsSummary(empId))
).subscribe(response => {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Contractsummary>(response);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
})
```

P.S. Don't forget to unsubscribe, since it looks like `currentEmployeeId` may not complete.